# Error running Virtual Box on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I installed Virtual Box regularly on Arch Linux using pacman:

```
pacman -S virtualbox
```

When i run `virtualbox` from the terminal, the GUI of the program is loaded but I can't use a virtual machine and I get this warning:

```
The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.12.5-1-ARCH) or it failed to
         load. Please reinstall the kernel module virtualbox-host-modules or
         if you don't use our stock kernel compile the modules with

           sudo dkms autoinstall
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, have you tried to do what the message suggests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I checked and I already had installed `virtualbox-host-modules` , then I tried to reinstall it. That wasn't enough. Then I tried the command `sudo dkms autoinstall`.
Dkms isn't installed by default so I had to install `dkms` package. Then I started the service by typing  `sudo systemctl enable dkms.service` . Then I could try with `sudo dkms autoinstall` again. I tried starting virtualbox again but I still got an error. Then I tried to manually load to module `vboxdrv` by typing `modprobe vboxdrv` . Now virtualbox is working.

Comment: In order to load kernel module automatically at boot, you have to create a file (which IMHO has to have suffix `.conf`) to `/etc/modules-load.d/`, and put the name of the module to be loaded inside the file. [Reference.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Loading)